Nav bar links not showing up using Tailwind CSS
I am putting together a new homepage using Tailwind CSS. The rest of the site already uses it. On the homepage I have a nav bar. There should be links in the middle of the nav bar (Home, About, Services) but they are not showing up.
When I put the same code in the Tailwind playground it works fine. Not sure what is wrong that is causing the middle links to not show up.
The site is Django.
An example page is at https://dev-app.metricsgeeks.com/.
The nav block I am adding looks like:
<nav class="bg-white dark:bg-gray-900 fixed w-full z-20 top-0 start-0 border-b border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-600">
  <div class="max-w-screen-xl flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between mx-auto p-4">

  <img src="static/assets/img/app_logo.png" class="h-8" alt="Flowbite Logo">

  <div class="flex md:order-2 space-x-3 md:space-x-0 rtl:space-x-reverse">
    <a href="#">
      <button type="button" class="text-dark bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-4 py-2 text-center dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800">Sign In</button>
    </a>
    <a href="{% url 'signup' %}">
      <button type="button" class="text-dark bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-4 py-2 text-center dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800">Create Account</button>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="items-center justify-between hidden w-full md:flex md:w-auto md:order-1" id="navbar-sticky">
    <ul class="flex flex-col p-4 md:p-0 mt-4 font-medium border border-gray-100 rounded-lg bg-gray-50 md:space-x-8 rtl:space-x-reverse md:flex-row md:mt-0 md:border-0 md:bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 md:dark:bg-gray-900 dark:border-gray-700">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="block py-2 px-3 text-dark bg-blue-700 rounded md:bg-transparent md:text-blue-700 md:p-0 md:dark:text-blue-500">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="block py-2 px-3 text-gray-900 rounded hover:bg-gray-100 md:hover:bg-transparent md:hover:text-blue-700 md:p-0 md:dark:hover:text-blue-500 dark:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-white md:dark:hover:bg-transparent dark:border-gray-700">About</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="block py-2 px-3 text-gray-900 rounded hover:bg-gray-100 md:hover:bg-transparent md:hover:text-blue-700 md:p-0 md:dark:hover:text-blue-500 dark:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-white md:dark:hover:bg-transparent dark:border-gray-700">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="block py-2 px-3 text-gray-900 rounded hover:bg-gray-100 md:hover:bg-transparent md:hover:text-blue-700 md:p-0 md:dark:hover:text-blue-500 dark:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-white md:dark:hover:bg-transparent dark:border-gray-700">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
</nav>


You have the "hidden" class in your css, remove it :
<div class="items-center justify-between hidden w-full md:flex md:w-auto md:order-1" id="navbar-sticky">


It seems like your output CSS is missing many Tailwind classes that appear in your markup. For example, the md:flex on the navbar that should make it show for larger viewports but its CSS rule is missing from the CSS. Consider checking:

The file(s) that contain Tailwind classes are covered by the content file globs in the Tailwind configuration. If Tailwind does not "see" a class name in the content in scans, it won't generate the CSS rule for it and thus the class name won't work.
You have run a Tailwind compilation since adding the classes. You may need to get Tailwind to rescan the content files for new class names so that it can generate new CSS rules for newly-used CSS classes.

